# How to call rest API(Start Process Instance) for Acitviti in JAVA

Tags: java, activiti

This is my java code.

```
ProcessEngines.getDefaultProcessEngine().getRuntimeService().startProcessInstanceByKey("myclcprocess");
```

server Details:

> Schema Details: Server HMECD000046v,
>   Schema Name: activiti,
>   Credentials- root, root, 
>   Proc Definition ID- 'myclcprocess:4:7907'

This is my first simple program. I'm getting NullPointerException. Please any one help me **how to configure?**. and **how to invoke the process?**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

need to create `Activiti.cfg.xml`. In that file need to configure the data source details
Example:

```
<bean id="processEngineConfiguration" class="org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneProcessEngineConfiguration" >
    <!-- Database configurations -->
    <property name="jdbcUrl" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost/activiti" />
    <property name="jdbcDriver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="jdbcUsername" value="root" />
    <property name="jdbcPassword" value="root" />
    <property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false" />
  </bean>
```

references:
http://krishnasblog.com/2012/05/07/4/
http://bpmn20inaction.blogspot.in/2010/12/activiti-spring-integration-example.html